# How to make font-size automatically adjust to mobile version

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am creating a website using Twitter Bootstrap; the website now looks OK on desktop or laptop but when I view in mobile the font-size does not adjust to the screen suitable size. Could someone told me how to fix that?

```
<section class="box">
   <img src="images/background2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Do you love to scuba dive? Are you looking for your next bid dive event?     
        </h1>
        <p>Look no further. Join ABI and other experienced divers throughout the year as we travel to amazing ocean resort destinations for state of the art diving experiences. Each trip will include
        multiple dives operated by experienced dive companies. All proceeds from these diving excursions will benefit the ABI Endowment Fund
        <a href="http://endowment.abi.org" target="_blank"> [endowment.abi.org]</a> 
        Do something you love while supporting the ABI Endowment Fund. Get more information about ABI's upcoming dive excursions.
       </p>
   </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really want the font size to be smaller? It might get hard to read on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { font-size: 1em;}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
    html { font-size: 70%; }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size: 80%; }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    html { font-size: 120%; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    html { font-size: 200%; }
}
```

Try this :)
**http://jsfiddle.net/yv5eu/**

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can use media queries as Nick has suggested. But a more fluid alternative is using Javascript to do the trick as Tushar has solved. If you're not comfortable with coding in JavaScript, FlowType.js is a lightweight jQuery plugin that is simple to use made for responsive fonts.